# Show modal loose my <select> style with chosen

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, select

## Problem 1:

I load modal windows dynamically like in this post [Dynamically load information to Twitter Bootstrap modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11003679/dynamically-load-information-to-twitter-bootstrap-modal). All works like a charm except the `<select>`. I've choose [Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/). The menu appears but not styled with Chosen.

---

## Problem 2:

In my code bellow (Modal Content load by jQuery), I need to insert again my script file (*.js) whereas they are already include into my index page...

---

## My index.php HTML code:

```
<div id="modal-user-infos" class="modal fade" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" id="modal-user-infos-content"></div>
</div>
[...]
all my scripts
[...]
```

## My JS call the modal:

```
$(".edit-item").click(function() {   
        var item_id  = $(this).attr('data-id');
        var modal_id = $(this).attr('data-modal');
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'assets/php/inc/modal/'+modal_id+'.php',
            data: 'item_id='+item_id,
            success: function(data) 
            {
                $('#modal-'+modal_id).modal('show');
                $('#modal-'+modal_id+'-content').show().html(data);
            }
        });
});
```

## My modal content load by jQuery:

```
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header text-center">
    <h2 class="modal-title">Informations</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <form id="update-user-info" action="assets/php/ajax/update-user-info.php" class="form-horizontal form-bordered">
      <select name="USR_Language" class="select-chosen" data-placeholder="Choose a language...">
        <option value="en-US">Anglais</option>
        <option value="es-ES">Espagnol</option>
        <option value="fr-CA">Français</option>
      </select>
      <div class="form-group form-actions">
        <div class="col-xs-6 text-right">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Save Changes</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you resolve your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try something like :

**Problem 1 :**

```
$(".edit-item").click(function() {   
        var item_id  = $(this).attr('data-id');
        var modal_id = $(this).attr('data-modal');
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'assets/php/inc/modal/'+modal_id+'.php',
            data: 'item_id='+item_id,
            success: function(data) 
            {
                $('#modal-'+modal_id).modal('show');
                $('#modal-'+modal_id+'-content').show().html(data);
                $('#update-user-info select').chosen();  // <--- HERE
            }
        });
});
```

**Problem 2 :**

I think you can't, it's already insered, so just call a function.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/alxlit/bootstrap-chosen < Try this. Its for better integration with BS3 and Chosen.