# Send parameter to Bootstrap modal window?

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, window

I have a problem, I cannot pass any parameters to a modal window (using Bootstrap 3), I tried using the solution stated in this link, but I cannot make it work:

[Dynamically load information to Twitter Bootstrap modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11003679/dynamically-load-information-to-twitter-bootstrap-modal)

(Solution kexxcream user).

But pressing the button, the display does not show me anything, apparently blocks, attached a picture below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UjvlO.png

I have attached the code (same code post above left);

HTML Code:

```
      <div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h3>Title</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">            
          <div id="modalContent" style="display:none;">

          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal" >Close</a>
      </div>
  </div>
```

JS Code:

```
    $("a[data-toggle=modal]").click(function() 
    {   
        var essay_id = $(this).attr('id');

        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'backend.php',
            data: 'EID='+essay_id,
            success: function(data) 
            {
                $('#myModal').show();
                $('#modalContent').show().html(data);
            }
        });
    });
```

Button:

```
<a href='#myModal' data-toggle='modal' id='2'> Edit </a>
```

PHP Code (backend.php):

```
<?php
$editId = $_POST['EID'];
?>
  <div class="jumbotron">
   <div class="container">
    <h1>The ID Selected is <?php echo $editId ?></h1>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: $editId = filter_var($_POST["id"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT); // just playing safe :)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

First of all you should fix modal HTML [structure](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals). Now it's not correct, you don't need class `.hide`:

```
<div id="edit-modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body edit-content">
                ...
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then links should point to this modal via `data-target` attribute:

```
<a href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" id="1" data-target="#edit-modal">Edit 1</a>
```

Finally Js part becomes very simple:

```
    $('#edit-modal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {

        var $modal = $(this),
            esseyId = e.relatedTarget.id;

        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'backend.php',
            data: 'EID=' + essayId,
            success: function(data) {
                $modal.find('.edit-content').html(data);
            }
        });
    })
```

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/4XnLTZ557qMegqRmWVwU?p=preview

Comment: Friend thank you very much for your help. He had many days searching the internet, and I could not solve the problem, but you solved my question immediately. I really am very grateful, I worked without problems. Again thank you very much. Greetings from Chile.

Comment: @dfsq if you have some spare time I'll thank you if you could take a look to this bounty question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47609994/jquery-how-to-pre-load-info-into-the-dom/47643047#47643047

Answer (score 55):

There is a better solution than the accepted answer, specifically using data-* attributes. Setting the  id to 1 will cause you issues if any other element on the page has id=1. Instead, you can do:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#yourModalID" data-yourparameter="whateverYouWant">Load</button>

<script>
$('#yourModalID').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
  var yourparameter = e.relatedTarget.dataset.yourparameter;
  // Do some stuff w/ it.
});
</script>
```

Comment: i had to use `e.relatedTarget.dataset.yourparameter` (in lower case) even though I used `data-yourParameter` in the markup. Don't know why.

Comment: Huh, good to know. I guess I've never actually camelCased a data-* attribute before. Thx!

Comment: Much better answer. Needs to be at top

Comment: I using the above solution in Yii2 application, it isnt working. :(

Comment: thanks, it works fine, using yourparameter (lower case)

Comment: Cool, thanks, answer updated to to use `yourparameter`.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution at:
[Passing data to a bootstrap modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10626885/passing-data-to-a-bootstrap-modal)

So simply use:

```
 $(e.relatedTarget).data('book-id');
```

with '`book-id`' is a attribute of modal with pre-fix '`data-`'

Answer (score 1):

I have found this better way , no need to remove data , just call the source of the remote content each time

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.class').click(function() {
        var id = this.id;
        //alert(id);checking that have correct id
        $("#iframe").attr("src","url?id=" + id);
        $('#Modal').modal({ 
            show: true 
        });
    });
});
```