# Bootstrap show.bs.modal not firing

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I am trying to pass the id of the element to the modal dialog. However, the event is not getting fired. I have looked at [bootstrap jquery show.bs.modal event won't fire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19279629/bootstrap-jquery-show-bs-modal-event-wont-fire) but it did not help. Here is what I do.

I build a set of links as follows.

```
// invitations is an array of id's retrieved from the back-end
for (var i = 0; i < invitations.length; i++) {
   var labelTxt = '<label><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" id=' + invitations[i] + ' data-target="#modalInvitation">' +  invitations[i] + '</a></label>';
   $('<div>').text($(labelTxt).appendTo('#myDiv'));
}
```

My modal dialog is as follows

```
<div id="modalInvitation" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title">Invite</h4>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-body">
            <button id="inviteBtn" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Invite</button>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Finally I call event, show.bs.modal as follows.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $(document).on('show.bs.modal',
        '#modalInvitation',
        function() {
            var inviteId = e.relatedTarget.id;
            alert(inviteId);
        });
});
```

However, the event show.bs.modal is not firing. Also referred to this [Send parameter to Bootstrap modal window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24323895/send-parameter-to-bootstrap-modal-window)

Comment: Are you getting an error in the JS console? The callback contains a reference to `e.relatedTarget`, but doesn't declare the parameter `e` in the `function()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, there was nothing wrong with the code. While stripping the code to the bare minimum I noticed that I had 2 versions of jQuery running, like so

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Removing the latter solves the problem. The problem still exists if I run just the latter. Not sure why though.